# How to make the latest Git commit become remote Head

Tags: git

New to Git and it was suddenly foisted on me from a simple TortoiseSVN.

I'm not sure if a need to do a rebase or what but I have a previous commit in a remote repository that may be the HEAD (not even sure how to check that) and the latest repository that has appeared to have branched without me requesting it.

[image: Move HEAD (?) back into "ifix1 origin/ifix"]

So bascially I want to move the branch that says "Removed EWS.." back to "ifix1 origin/ifix1" so that the last commit becomes "ifix1 origin/ifix1 Removed EWS.."

Comment: Are you wanting to make `ifix1` and `origin/ifix1` (I believe these are both branches) point to the "Removed EWS" commit?

Comment: Which UI are you using for Git – TortoiseGit or what? Are `git` CLI answers okay?

Comment: Also: Generally, Git only uses "HEAD" to describe the current commit in your _local_ repository (thus the local HEAD is already at "Removed EWS" commit.) However it _doesn't_ have a single "remote HEAD"; each branch has its own head commit.

Comment: Hi @heavyd    I have worked out that the commit at **ifix1** **origin/ifix1** is the HEAD revision so yes, I would like the "Removed EWS" commit to become the HEAD or the above branches to point to the "Removed EWS" commit

Comment: Hi @grawity I am using TortoiseGit

Comment: OK @grawity.   I think I am beginning to understand a bit more.  Basically, the "Removed EWS" commit is my local repository HEAD and the **ifix1** **origin/ifix1** is my remote repository HEAD on the **ifix1** **origin/ifix1** branches if I get what you are saying...So how do I get the local rep "Removed EWS" commit to become my remote rep HEAD on the **ifix1** **origin/ifix1** branches..?  Cheers

Comment: Note to all, I haved pushed the "Removed EWS" commit out to my remote repository but it wasn't made the HEAD version....

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume 'Removed EWS' is the head of master (local) and origin/master (remote). (It's cut off in your snip).

I'm also going to assume you currently have master checked out.

Solution:

Check out ifix1 (Right-click on ifix1 and choose Checkout)

Move ifix1 (Right-click on Removed EWS and choose Reset current branch to here)

Push ifix1 (This will move origin/ifix1)